# Temperature of a particle moving in a gravity field

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, temperature, ideal-gas

I have a seemingly simple question that is still puzzling to me.
The temperature of an atom is proportional to its kinetic energy. If an atom now moves upwards in a gravity field, its kinetic energy changes: $E_h = E_0 - hgm$.
So $T_h < T_0$, where $T_h$ is the temperature of the atom at height h and $T_0$ is at height 0. The reason this is puzzling to me is that it seems the particle could induce a flow of energy between other particles at height h and at height 0, even if both initially also had the same temperature $T_0$: energy would flow down, the temperature at the top would decrease towards $T_h$. This seems paradoxical to me. How would the system really behave?

Comment: "The temperature of an atom is proportional to its kinetic energy." No. The average energy divided by the number of particles is not the same thing as the energy of an individual particle.

Comment: To understand how the system behaves, you can compute the partition function for N atoms in a gravitational field.

Comment: See also the [adiabatic lapse rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lapse_rate).

Comment: @Chemomechanics Thanks! I am surprised though, I thought that the temperature difference between lower and higher atmosphere was due only to the air near the ground being heated by the ground (-> indirectly by the sun). It still sounds strange to me that a temperature difference should be created "spontaneously" since I thought different temperatures almost always equalize spontaneously.

Comment: @hft thanks, I will try that out, see if I can get it done with my limited knowledge of statistical mechanics

Comment: It's called "adiabatic" because the upward/downward motion that causes expansion/compression and consequently cooling/heating occurs much faster than temperature equilibration.

Answer (score 2):

Temperature is a measure of the *average* kinetic energy of an ensemble of particles. So, defining one atom's temperature makes no sense.